# \$V_{BE}\$ decreasing with \$V_{CE}\$ at constant \$I_B\$ in a BJT common emitter?

Tags: transistors, bjt, measurement, common-emitter

I took measurements on a TIP31 common emitter BJT transistor. The circuit was the one in picture

[image]

I observed a fact which seems quite unusual. 
Keeping \$I_B\$ constant, for different values  of \$V_{CE}\$ I measured the corresponding \$V_{BE}\$.

Plotting  \$V_{BE}\$ vs. \$V_{CE}\$ it is clear that \$V_{BE}\$ decreases if \$V_{CE}\$ increases.

This fact should be in contrast with input characteristics I found, like this one

[image]

Also using Multisim for a simulation, I find that \$V_{CE}\$ should increase with \$V_{BE}\$ at \$I_B\$ constant.

Is this behaviour really unusual or could there be an explanation for it?

Comment: What Base current and Collector voltages did you input, and what Vbe variation did you observe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's referred to as the Early effect.

The effective base width is modulated by the voltage on the collector.

Its major effect is to increase the collector current.

[BJT non-ideal effects](https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter5/ch5_4.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I've read about the Early effect, but I cannot understand how the increase of width of the base (while \$V_{CE}\$ increases) causes \$V_{BE}\$ to  decrease (whereas it is clear to me how this make the current \$I_{C}\$ increase) I read the link posted but I don't think I found an explanation there.. May I ask you to give a brief explanation of how Early effect (i.e. increase of base width) comes in to play here?

Comment: Sören, VBE does not decrease (automatically). You must look at  it from another viewpoint. An increase in VCE results in a broader depletion area (C-B region). That is the normal expected behaviour of a pn junction that is reverse biased. This causes a further reduction of the B-E junction width (which is forward biased). Hence, a smaller VBE value is necessary to produce the same collector current as before.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I was reading again, do you mean "base" current in the last sentence instead of "collector" current? (Because it's base current that is being constant)